# Encode request payload in GWT RPC call

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I am using GWT to create my web-app.

When making RPC call from client side (browser), in inspect element my **Request Payload** is as below :

```
7|0|8|https://xxxx.xxxx.in/TestProject/in.TestProject.Main/|87545F2996A876761A0C13CD750EA654|in.TestProject.client.CustomerClassService|check_User_Login|java.lang.String/2004016611|in.TestProject.Beans.CustomerBean/3980370781|UserId|Password|1|2|3|4|3|5|5|6|7|8|6|0|0|0|0|0|CustId|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
```

In this request all the details like username, password & custid are displayed in the request payload.

My question is, is it possible to encode OR hide those details from request payload?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/a/gebs.ro/document/d/1eG0YocsYYbNAtivkLtcaiEE5IOF5u4LUol8-LL0TIKU/edit#heading=h.amx1ddpv5q4m

Comment: Thanks @Ovi Faur, but i didn't get any solution from this document as it has nothing related to encode or hide request payload.

Comment: Yes..that's why I just commented..maybe explains some more :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong level of abstraction. What's the point of encoding/"hidding" these values in the payload? Everything you exchange between the server and client can be intercepted anyway... **unless you use HTTPS**. It ensures safe/encrypted communication between the server and client. Don't try to be "clever" and only encrypt part of the communication/payload, **just use HTTPS**.

> But my concern is client itself should not be able to seen which method call we are making, parameter type in the request, parameter values etc. It should be hidden from client.

But those parameter values were input by the user himself or are hardcoded somewhere in the application (which the user will always be able to see/decipher, because his browser has to). So what you are trying to achieve is [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and is never a good idea. I'd focus my attention and efforts into securing the endpoints (GWT-RPC services), validating the input sent there, etc.

You have to remember one thing - that the user has access to the source code (compiled and minified, but still) of the client-side part of your application. So:

- He'll always be able to figure out how to communicate with your server, because your application has to.
- He can modify the application to send malicious requests - even if you created some hypothetical way of encoding parameters/addresses. Just find a place just before the encoding is done and voila. Firebug and other Developer Tools will help you immensely in this.

So "securing" client-side in this way is meaningless (of course, CSRF, XSS, etc. *should* be your concern), a malicious user will always bypass it because you have to give him all the tools to do it - otherwise, a "normal" user (or rather his browser) wouldn't be able to use your application.

Comment: Thanks @Igor Klimer, But my concern is client itself should not be able to seen which method call we are making, parameter type in the request, parameter values etc. It should be hidden from client.

Comment: Please see my updated answer - it was too long for a comment.